# Как сохранить проект в .exe?

Tags: eclipse, java

Создал проект в Eclipse IDE, подключил к нему дополнительно mySQL. Как сохранить проект так, чтобы его можно было запускать на другом компьютере просто с .exe?

**UPD:** или в jar.

Comment: Прошу автора пересмотреть ответы на вопрос.  
  
Почитать про тему подробнее можно здесь  
http://www.javalobby.org/articles/java2exe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `.exe` не получится, для выполнения java-проекта нужна JVM.
Соберите проект в jar-файл  [вот пример](http://ru.wikihow.com/создать-исполняемый-файл-в-Eclipse). Runnable-jar тоже запускается по двойному нажатию, как и exe.

Comment: А как в .jar сохранить? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: ссылка есть в ответе. 
Продублирую http://ru.wikihow.com/создать-исполняемый-файл-в-Eclipse

Comment: @111xbot111

  File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable jar file

Answer (score 3):

При всей нубкости вопроса смысл в этом есть. Существуют 2 подхода к конвертации JAR в EXE:

1. Оборачивание JAR в EXE при этом на клиентской машине требуется наличие JVM - по сути EXE здесь просто лончер `java -jar myapp.jar`.
2. Более хитрый способ, когда EXE уже содержит в себе JVM и при запуске EXE создается маленькая Java машинка, в среде которой и запускается JAR.

Ссылок не даю, ибо тема многократно обсуждалась и гуглится по ключевым словам:

> jar to exe